Symmetry arising from modular arithmetic
Given natural numbers $1<k<n$ where $k\not\equiv \pm1 \pmod n$, $f(m)$ is a function on integer $m\pmod n$ with $f(j-ki)=f(i-kj),\,\forall i,j\in\mathbf Z$. Is $f$ constant?
It seems I should look at the cyclic permutation structure obtained from $i\rightarrow -ki\pmod n$ then translate it.
This problem arises from looking at a variation on the symmetric circulant matrix where the successive rows are shifted (to the right) not by $1$ but $1<k<n-1$ positions.

this is not clear.  Are $k,n$ fixed ?  If, say, we take $k=1$, then you are asking if $f(i-j)=f(j-i)$ implies $f$ is constant, which is clearly false (consider $f(x)=x^2$ for instance).  So...what are you asking?

@lulu: I said "Given ... $k<n$". So $k,n$ are fixed. You are right that I missed the condition $1<k$. I have just fixed it. I am more confident for $1<k$ and $n$ being coprime.

$n$ being coprime to what?  $k$?  That condition doesn't appear in your post.
Anyway, if you take $k=n-1\equiv -1\pmod n$ your condition comes to $f(i+j)=f(j+i)$ which is always true.  Voting to close the question.

@lulu: $n$ is coprime to $k$. You are right. How about adding the conditions $k\not\equiv 1\pmod n$ and $k\not\equiv -1\pmod n$?

It's a terrible idea to state a conjecture, without any context at all, and then repeatedly add new conditions as counterexamples are discovered.

If you have some context for the conjecture, please edit your post to add it.  As it stands, we don't even know what space the function maps to.  I get that it's range is $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ but does it take values there?  Does it take integer values?  Something else?

@lulu: The function is just there to express the equivalence relation, there is no need to specify the range. Alternatively I can ask if there is only one equivalence class. These two formulations are equivalent, right? The reason I want to use the function formulation is that I want to add a variation later.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

No need for a chat.  I think your question should be edited to show context.  An easy step would be to solve it for small $n$.  And I do think the equivalence relation description is far clearer than what you have written.

@lulu: I just added the context. Care to take a look?

Some errors have been corrected.  My posted solution works for odd prime $n$.  I need primality to get the invertibility of $(k\pm 1)\pmod n$.  The pair $(n,k)=(8,3)$ is a counterexample even if you add the condition $\gcd(n,k)=1$.  I think you might do better if you add the condition $\gcd(k\pm 1, n)=1$ but, as I said, it's never a good idea to keep adding conditions to respond to counterexamples.

@lulu: Very nice! Thank you! I was just reading your answer and thought we just need the condition gcd$(k\pm1, n)=1$ as you said just now -- I had the feeling before there should be some coprime conditions. :-) It would be better if you add this to your answer to make it more general if you please. Regarding changing conditions, it is the natural process of exploring, isn't it?

I don't think coprimality is the issue, as my counterexamples show.   Both the cases $(n,k)=(8,3)$ and $(n,k)=(15,4)$ are relatively prime.  Even for odd $n$ , you'd need to add the condition that $\gcd(k\pm 1, n)=1$ but that's not enough since you also need to exclude $k^2\equiv 1\pmod n$.  If you want to find a workable generalization, I suggest working out a lot of examples.  Maybe I have found all the bad cases, but it's much more likely that I haven't.

@lulu: I meant some kind of coprimality not necessarily between $k$ and $n$, but something like between $k+a$ and $n$ for one or more constant integers $a$. But never mind about that as that is just my vague feeling prior. It is all moot after you have solved this problem and given the necessary and sufficient condition gcd$(k\pm1,n)=1$.

The question, in essence, asks that, given $k\not \equiv \pm 1\pmod n$, and given $a\pmod n$ can we always find $i, j\pmod n$ such that $$i+kj\equiv 0 \quad \quad \&\quad \quad j+ki\equiv a \tag1$$
Where all congruences are $\pmod n$.   To see this, note that, if we have this pair $i,j$ then $f(0)=f(a)$ but $a$ was arbitrary.
Partial Result  The claim is True for odd prime $n$.
To prove that $i,j$ exist, at least when $n$ is odd:
We add the two congruences to get $$(i+j)(1+k)\equiv a \implies i+j\equiv a(1+k)^{-1} \tag2$$
Where, of course, that inverse exists since $k\not \equiv -1$ and all non-zero residues are invertible modulo a prime.
Similarly, subtracting yields $$(i-j)(k-1)\equiv a\implies i-j\equiv a(k-1)^{-1} \tag3$$
It is now easy to solve for $i,j$:  $$i\equiv\frac{ak}{k^2-1},\quad \quad j\equiv-\frac{a}{k^2-1}. \tag4$$
As these expressions require inverting $2\pmod n$, my argument requires $n$ to be odd.
The conjecture is False for $n=8$, even if you add the condition that $\gcd(k,n)=1$.  To see this, let $(n,k)=(8,3)$.  Then, if $$i+3j\equiv 0\pmod 8$$  we deduce $$i\equiv -3j\pmod 8 \implies j+3i\equiv j-j\equiv 0 \pmod 8$$ so $0$ isn't equivalent to any non zero value.
The same argument shows that the conjecture is False for composite $n$, as in general you would then get non-trivial solutions to $k^2\equiv 1 \pmod n$. For instance, $(n,k)=(15,4)$ will be a counterexample. Of course, for primes the only solutions are $\pm 1$ which we excluded at the start.

It is better to use the following substitution solution with apparent symmetry.
Let us reformulate and resolve Equation $(1)$
\begin{align}
  i+kj&\equiv b \tag{1.1} \\
  j+ki&\equiv a \tag{1.2}
\end{align}
From Equation (1.2), we have
$$j\equiv a-ki.$$
Substitute the above into Equation $(1.1)$, we have
$$ka+(1-k^2)i\equiv b$$
or
$$i\equiv\frac{b-ka}{1-k^2}.$$
By the symmetry of Equation $(1.1),(1.2)$,
$$j\equiv\frac{a-kb}{1-k^2}.$$

Excellent! Accepted. It would be even better if you change the condition to gcd$(k\pm1,n)=1$ just as you said in your comment at the top to make your answer more general.

Ah, $n$ still needs to be odd on top of gcd$(k\pm1,n)=1$ for the two equations to hold, since we need to divide by $2$, right?

Yes, that's a separate condition.

Would you say, which seems true from your solution, that these conditions, i.e. $n$ being odd and gcd$(k\pm1,n)=1$, are the necessary conditions for the constancy of $f$ or for the two equations at the top of your answer to hold?

Well, they seem to be sufficient conditions since they allow my argument to go through.  Are they necessary?  To determine that, I'd look at examples.  For any given pair $(n,k)$ it's easy to test, so I'd test a lot of cases.

It seems Equation $(2)$ and $(3)$ require $\frac a{k\pm1}$ be defined for every $a$ and $\frac12$ be defined as well. Would that be enough to prove the necessity?

Yes...I believe it would.

It seems the simplified expression in Equation $(4)$ does not need $\frac12$. So we only need gcd$(k^2-1,n)=1$ and $n$ needs not be odd.

I don't see how you found those expressions, and they seem asymmetric.  Why does one have a $k$ in the numerator but not the other?  The original congruences are symmetric.  To be sure, it may be the case that the assumptions on $k$ may imply that the factors of $2$ cancel out, I have not thought about that.

Yes, it is because $k+1$ and $k-1$ always have the same parity. The above solution method is not reversible so it needs to be checked at the end. A better solution would be to use substitution, e.g. $i=-kj$ and substitute this into the second equation of Equation $(1)$. As a matter of fact, my edition of your answer did not reflect all the detailed consideration as stated above. We should change it accordingly.

I don't understand.  Why are your results for $i,j$ asymmetric?  Shouldn't $k$ in either in both numerators or neither?  And just knowing that $k+1, k-1$ have the same parity doesn't tell you that all factors of $2$ cancel.  Have you tested your formulas in examples?

The asymmetry is only apparent, coming from the apparent asymmetry of Equation $(1)$ using the special value $0$ on the right hand side. If you replace $0$ with a variable say $b$, you will make the symmetry apparent. See my edit above.
